# Font rendering / smoothing issue in Webkit with jQuery Slider Revolution (WP plugin version)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, fonts, smoothing

I didn't manage to find a fix to solve that issue yet. I've tried solutions offered in that similar post ["Safari rendering page fonts thinner with jQuery slider on page"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049524/safari-rendering-page-fonts-thinner-with-jquery-slider-on-page) involving these CSS properties: `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` and `-webkit-backface-visibility: visible` / `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`.

This is a Safari (Webkit)-only problem which happens on every page of this site: http://dev.gaudissard.com, in the header section only.

All the text (nav, dropdown menus, buttons) positioned above Slider Revolution is fine and displays with its regular weight... until Slider Revolution starts, thinning out the font display (kinda switching back and forth between font weights/smoothing).

From what I've read it looks like it's a font smoothing issue due to CSS3 animations happening in the layers below (z-index).

Some help would really be appreciated as even the (premium) plugin support team didn't answer my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**Problem solved!** Instead of `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` I used `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` (not in the `<html>` element but only where needed) and it made the font used in the header look thicker and great.